# Where am I going wrong in my cs50 pset 7 10.sql nested query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, cs50

I am currently trying to find the names of all people who have directed a movie that received a rating of at least 9.0
the scheme for these tables is

```
CREATE TABLE movies (

                    id INTEGER,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    year NUMERIC,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                );
CREATE TABLE stars (

                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE directors (

                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE ratings (

                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                rating REAL NOT NULL,
                votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE people (

                id INTEGER,
                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                birth NUMERIC,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
```

MY SQL QUERY IS :

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT person_id FROM directors WHERE movie_id IN ( 
    SELECT id FROM movies WHERE id IN (
        SELECT movie_id FROM ratings WHERE votes >= 9.0)));
```

This however fails the check50 test, and gives incorrect output. Can anyone help me with where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's part of `SELECT DISTINCT` - and works on the whole selected rows. Remove those extra parentheses, and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM ...` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec says (emphasis added)

> In `10.sql`, write a SQL query to list the names of all people who have directed a movie that received a **rating** of at least 9.0.

The query does not filter on the `ratings.rating` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct name 
from directors 
join people on directors.person_id = people.id 
join ratings on directors.movie_id = ratings.movie_id 
where rating >= 9.0;
```